# Pycharm 'end=' statement not working?

Tags: python, pycharm

So i'm currently learning Python and I code it on the Pycharm IDE. I was trying to write a function but for some reason Pycharm wont accept the 'end=' statement saying something like its not defined.

Here is my code

```
def fib(n):
    a,b=1,0
    while a < n:
        print (a, end=' ')
        a,b=b,b+a

fib(1000)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
line 7
    print (a, end=' ')
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's only doing this on Pycharm. When I tried it on the dafult Python IDLE it worked just fine. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: What are you trying to print? Just a blank line?

Comment: this is python3 syntax and you clearly use python2.x, change it to `print a, `

Comment: @Ev. `end=' '` continue next print here

Comment: You need to change your interpreter from python 2 to 3 in pycharm settings

Comment: do `alt + s` then click on the module your working on click interpreter and choose python 3

Comment: Oh so Pycharm is using python 2 by default then?

Comment: Depends on your installations, go to file - project settings - project interpreter

Comment: Turns out my interpreter was in fact set to 2.7 instead of 3.5(i thought i uninstalled python 2 after I got 3 lol) Thnaks so much guys!

Answer (score 4):

As already answered in comments, only python3 have keywords arguments for [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print):

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

For python2, [`print`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) is a statement defined as this and have no keywords arguments:

```
print_stmt ::=  "print" ([expression ("," expression)* [","]]
                | ">>" expression [("," expression)+ [","]])
```

You can either switch to python3 or disable the statement and use the [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print) function with this future line at the top of your module:
`from __future__ import print_function`

```
$ python2
>>> help(print) # fail because print is a statement in python2
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> help(print)
>>> Help on built-in function print in module __builtin__:

print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)
.....
```